# NixOS reproducible users and packages?

Tags: linux, configuration, package-management, provisioning, nixos

I'm new to [NixOS](https://nixos.org/nixos/manual/) and trying to learn its concepts. One of the reasons I'm excited about it is I'm hoping it will be able to give me a reproducible system configuration, similar to using [Ansible for localhost](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_delegation.html#local-playbooks). However, I am not sure how to achieve this.

I am aware of [`environment.systemPackages` in `/etc/nixos/configuration.nix`](https://nixos.org/nixos/manual/sec-package-management.html), but these are system-wide packages only. I also know that the [`nix-env`](https://nixos.org/nix/manual/#sec-nix-env) command can install a package for a user, but I'd rather declare such a package in a file that I can check into source control.

Is there a particular file I can configure (similar to a playbook) where I could declare a set of packages for a user? Or at least specify its ["user environment"](http://nixos.org/nix/manual/#fig-user-environments) or ["profiles"](http://nixos.org/nix/manual/#profiles) (not sure which term is correct)?

Ideally I could take a few files, copy them to another computer, run a command, and it's at the same state as the old computer, including multiple users with different sets of packages.

Finally, does my use case mean that I should never use [`nix-env`](https://nixos.org/nix/manual/#sec-nix-env) to install packages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I asked the folks on the Freenode #nixos IRC channel, and they led me to this answer.

I need to create a [`~/.nixpkgs/config.nix`](http://nixos.org/nixpkgs/manual/#chap-packageconfig) file. In that file, I need to create a [package collection](https://nixos.org/wiki/Howto_keep_multiple_packages_up_to_date_at_once) using the [buildEnv function](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/tree/master/pkgs/build-support/buildenv) and install it with `nix-env`.

Installing ad-hoc packages using [`nix-env`](http://nixos.org/nix/manual/#sec-nix-env) does not update `~/.nixpkgs/config.nix`, so for my use case I would want to avoid doing that. Although, it is worth noting that installing ad-hoc packages using `nix-env` is still useful for experimentation since installing the package collection using the `--remove-all` switch would remove everything not in that package collection.